# Il y en a de biens étranges : analyse syntaxique

Tags: syntaxe, en, partitif

Comment analyser syntaxiquement la phrase "Il y en a de bien étranges." ?

Je ne suis pas sûr de la relation entre "en" et "avoir" et entre "de" et "étranges".

Ci-dessous ma tentative analyse, où "de" est un article partitif, et "étranges" modifie "en".

[image]

nsubj = nominal subject;
iobj = indirect object;
obj = object;
amod = adjectival modifier;
det = determiner;
advmod = adverbial modifier
(Voir https://universaldependencies.org/)

Comment: Il faut un antécédent qui expliquerait l'anaphore.

Comment: "Personne ne s’occupe de lui, il n’a besoin de personne. Il peut même se passer des bateaux-paillassons, et des cavernes du carreau, avec leur faune fantastique. Son corps lui suffit. Quelle source d’amusement ! Il passe des heures à regarder ses ongles, en riant aux éclats. Ils ont tous des physionomies différentes, et ressemblent à des gens qu’il connaît. Il les fait causer ensemble, et danser, ou se battre. — Et le reste du corps !…"

Comment: [suite] "Il continue l’inspection de tout ce qui lui appartient. Que de choses étonnantes ! Il y en a de bien étranges, il s’absorbe curieusement dans leur vue. Il fut rudement attrapé parfois, quand on le surprit ainsi. "  https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/L%E2%80%99Aube_(Jean-Christophe)/I

Comment: Voilà, vous l'avez posté: Que de **choses étonnantes** ! Il y **en a de bien étranges.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***De*** n'est ni un article indéfini, ni un article partitif dans cette phrase.

Il s'agit d'une préposition, identifiée comme *particule de soutien* dans le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de).

> **De**, préposition
> [...]
> **II.−** De marque une relation syntaxique; il est introducteur de substantif, de pronom ou d'infinitif en fonction de complément, de sujet, d'attribut, d'apposition, ou en fonction expressive.
> [...]
> **B.−** [De introducteur de sujet, d'attributs, d'apposition; de signifie « le fait de », en parlant d'un fait particulier.]
> [...]
> **3.** de + apposition [L'apposition (attribut raccourci), l'appellation ou la dénomination est introduite par de, particule de soutien, après un substantif]
> [...]
> **c)** [Dénomination de choses (avec un nom commun) :]
> [...]
> **α)** [Après un substantif déterminé par un adjectif numéral cardinal ou un adjectif exprimant une quantité, un nombre.]
> [...]
> ♦ [L'emploi de la particule de soutien de est obligatoire]
> [lorsque le subst. est remplacé par en.] − *On en fait [des nez] aujourd'hui de bien élégants, dit le docteur* (About, Nez notaire, 1862, p. 204). *Tous les matins les médecins, en faisant leur ronde, en trouvaient sept ou huit de morts* (Erckmann - Chatrian, Conscrit 1813, 1864, p. 141).

La phrase peut se reconstruire comme suit :

> **Il y a** (parmi ce qui lui appartient) **des choses bien étranges.**

Comment: Vous êtes d'accord que *en* remplace bien *choses* ?

Comment: Oui, ce sont bien des choses qui sont bien étranges.

Comment: Donc on a une relation syntaxique de modifieur de *en* vers *de* puis une relation complément de *de* vers *étranges* ?

Comment: J'avoue ne pas savoir m'avancer aussi loin dans l'analyse. J'ai atteint mon niveau d'incompétence :-) Il me semble que *en* et *de* ne font qu'un, un peu comme la négation *ne* ... * pas*, mais en plus indissociable.

Comment: Vous diriez que l'exemple de mon post est grammaticalement identique à *il y en a plein de taille différentes* ? (Ici, *taille* est un nom, contrairement à *étranges* qui est un adjectif)

Comment: Identiques, je ne sais pas, mais similaires, sûrement : *Il y en a plein (il y a plein de choses), elles (ces choses) ont des tailles différentes* et *il y en a (il y a des choses), elles (ces choses) sont bien étranges*

Answer (score 0):

« De » n'est pas l'article partitif mais l'article indéfini; c'est la forme que prend l'article indéfini « des » lorsque placé avant un adjectif.

- Il y a des maisons qui sont grandes dans cette rue.
- Il y a de grandes maisons dans cette rue.

http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/article-indefini.html#045

La relation entre « en » et « avoir » est appelé une relation de complément, cependant ce n'est pas exactement de « avoir » qu'il s'agit, ni non plus de COD ou autre complément ni de « en » tout seul ; « en » fait partie du complément du *présentatif* « il y a ».

> (LBU édition 14, § **1069**) On appelle souvent complément du présentatif le mot ou le syntagme qu'il introduit. On peut parler de complément ou de régime de l'introducteur, sauf lorsque l'élément introduit a une autre fonction (comme celle de sujet, etc.)

https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-33068.php

La phrase équivaut à la suivante lorsqu'on utilise un remplacement pour le pronom « en ».

- Il y a des éléments dans cet ensemble qui sont bien étranges.

« En » remplace « des éléments dans cet ensemble », où « élément » et  « ensemble » sont les termes généraux en l'absence d'un contexte particulier.

- Voici des poupées articulées. Il y en a de bien étranges. (*Dans ce cas-ci, les « éléments »  sont les poupées et l'« ensemble » est le lot de poupées articulées qui a été mentionné*)
- Voici des poupées articulées. Il y a des poupées dans ce lot qui sont bien étranges.

On voit donc que le  complément du présentatif est « des poupées dans ce lot qui sont bien étranges ». Puisque le centre du présentatif est « des poupées dans ce lot » et que « des poupées dans ce lot » est le remplacement de « en », il s'ensuit que « en » est le *centre du complément du représentatif* « il y a ».

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour votre réponse. Maintiendriez vous votre analyse après avoir pris connaissance du contexte de la phrase (voir commentaires de mon post plus haut, mais je reproduis ici) : "Que de choses étonnantes ! Il y en a de bien étranges." Merci à Lambie pour son aide, je m'excuse d'avoir oublié de donner ces infos importantes.

Comment: @starckman Oui, la nature précise de l'antécédent est immatérielle, et on peut s'en passer entièrement ; la forme même de la phrase implique qu'il existe un antécédent, qui dans certains cas ne sera pas explicite, et qu'il faudra alors construire (c'est à dire que « en » ne peut pas être autre chose que le pronom). Cela suffit pour mener le raisonnement à sa conclusion. Vous devriez vous en rendre compte en construisant quelques exemples ; il vont vous montrer qu'il ne s'agit que d'un schèma qui est répété et que le contenu précis n'a aucune importance.